# how to mock s3.Object for an AWS lambda function in AWS

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-unittest

I have a simple lambda function, and because I am new to Python, I am not able to write test cases for that function. So, the task is very simple, I uploading an xml document to s3, and returning the url. Below is the code in the main python file:

Edit 2: the purpose of below code is to make a xml out of a JSON payload, which is passed in as an argument root, and upload it to s3. s3 already has a bucket s3-encora-task, and I have to upload output.xml. I have to write unit test for that condition.

```
def uploaddata(root):
    xmlstr = minidom.parseString(ET.tostring(root)).toprettyxml(indent="   ")
    string_out = io.StringIO()
    string_out.write(xmlstr)
    s3.Object('s3-encora-task', 'output.xml').put(Body=string_out.getvalue())
    location = boto3.client('s3').get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket_name)['LocationConstraint']
    url = "https://s3-%s.amazonaws.com/%s/%s" % (location, bucket_name, 'output.xml')
    return url
```

I get error in the line:

```
s3.Object('s3-encora-task', 'output.xml').put(Body=string_out.getvalue())
```

Below is the error:

raise NoCredentialsError()
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

I have experience in writing Junit test classes but I am having trouble in making a comparison(in the way of writing) of Junit and unittest, and so not able to articulate my question. So, I have below questions:

1. In my python file, I don't have a class.I am instantiating s3 like this outside of methods: s3 = boto3.resource('s3'). So , how can I mock this s3 object and pass to the method, so that mock object is used.
2. In my test class, i am importing the main python as : import jsontoxmlconverter as converter
   and then using converter.<> for unit testing, but the method doesn't take s3 as an argument, so again, how can I pass s3 mock object.
3. I have read few things about using moto to mock s3, but not able to figure out, how the object is getting passed, so any more info on that would help.

Thanks in Advance!!

Edit 1:
Below is the current code in my test class:

```
     import jsontoxmlconverter as converter
    def test_jsontoxml_happyflow(self):
        with open('jsonData.txt') as json_file:
            data = json.load(json_file)
        mock = Mock()
        mock.patch('converter.s3')
        result = converter.jsontoxml(data, context={})
```

Comment: It would be possible to provide a working example if the question included whatever test code you've written so far, but the short of it is that you want to use `mock.patch`.

Comment: I am actually lost in how to take this at first place. I am adding the code that I have till now in my test class.Thanks

Comment: Your test doesn't call the `uploaddata` function at all, so why are you worried about how to mock s3 within that function?

Comment: Sorry, uploaddata is called from jsontoxml function, and so the error is coming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `mock.patch`:

```
import jsontoxmlconverter as converter
from mock import patch

def test_jsontoxml_happyflow(self):
    with patch('jsontoxmlconverter.s3') as mock_s3:
        # make whatever adjustments to mock_s3 as needed
        result = converter.uploaddata("foo")
```

Note that you need to tell `patch` which module you want to patch s3 in.  When you use `patch` as a context manager, the patch only applies within the context, which makes it easy to isolate changes like this and guarantee that they don't affect other tests.  The `mock_s3` object available within the context is a `mock.Mock` object that takes the place of `s3`; you can freely reassign its attributes before calling the function that will depend on them.

Comment: with patch('jsontoxmlconverter.s3') as mock_s3: in this line, jsontoxmlconverter.s3 -> jsontoxmlconverter is the python file, and s3 should be a global variable? Also, for example for the below lines of code in my main class:
s3.Object('s3-encora-task', 'output.xml').put(Body=string_out.getvalue())
location = boto3.client('s3').get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket_name)['LocationConstraint']
so, how can I use mock_s3 to mock those 2 lines?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you tried running the code, or if you did, how the result differed from what you were looking for.  I think just patching the `s3` module with a mock should at least prevent the exception from being raised; making the mock object do something more useful is up to you, since you didn't describe what you want the mocked `s3` to actually do.

Comment: If you were to provide a minimum reproducible example (like provide a test and all of the code that's being tested) and just say what you want to have happen, you'd probably have fully working code at this point -- if you just say "how do I use this to mock?" you're going to get a general example (like what I provided) and have to fill in the blanks yourself.  :)  The code you've provided and your description are both too incomplete for me to be able to fix the code for you.

Comment: I have updated Edit2, with comments. Can you please check.

Comment: There still isn't enough code here to actually run.  You still have a test that calls a function you haven't defined and you still haven't said what exactly you want the test to cover (which is hard to do since you're not sharing the actual code you're testing).  The edits are making things less clear, not more.

Comment: the function uploaddata is being called from another function, and this function passes an elementtree object to uploaddata, which is in argument of uploaddata. I have written the below test for uploaddata function:
    def test_jsontoxml_uploaddata(self):
        root = ET.Element("Reservation")
        string_out = io.StringIO()
        with patch('jsontoxmlconverter.s3') as mock_s3:
            mock_s3.Object('s3-encora-task', 'output.xml').put(Body=string_out)
        converter.uploaddata(root)

Comment: Below is the error I am getting:
Below is the error I am getting: raise NoCredentialsError()
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials